# How to Stop GPSD daemon?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gps

I am trying to use the GPSD as a server, that is: everything must be done by command line, such as: `gpsd --help`.

I read [the documentation here](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/troubleshooting.html), which says that.in order to let gpsd work as server, you need to stop or kill the gpsd daemon first.

But I do not know how.

I ran `service --status-all` and it shows me the list of running daemons, which included gpsd:

```
[ - ]  gpsd
```

is it still working or stopped?

I also tried to use `start-stop-daemon -k` but it did not work, I just get shown the help when I try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read from [service man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/service.8.html):

> `service --status-all` runs all init scripts, in alphabetical order, with the status command.  The status is `[ + ]` for running services, `[ - ]`
>          for stopped services and `[ ? ]` for services without a 'status' command.  This option only calls status for sysvinit jobs; upstart  jobs  can
>          be queried in a similar manner with initctl list.

So, answering your question, YES, it is stopped.

**To get the** **status** of any daemon with the following:

```
start-stop-daemon -T --name gpsd
```

or if you know `gpsd`'s PID:

```
start-stop-daemon -T --pid 0123
```

**To kill/stop it**, run any (note that the `-K` is a capital letter):

```
start-stop-daemon -K --name gpsd
start-stop-daemon -K --pid 4567
```

---

Sources:

[start-stop-daemon man pages for 14.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html)

[service man pages for 14.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/service.8.html)

Comment: @Zanna changed it, hope it's better now

Comment: seems fine now, +1. Unfortunately it wasn't me who downvoted so not able to fix that

Comment: It's okey. I appreciate your feedback, @Zanna, I count on being able to improve my answers/contributions :)

Comment: @M.Becerra:  Thank you for your answer, I tried to use this command **start-stop-daemon -K --name gpsd** and I received this message:"**No gpsd found running; none killed.**" and I thought **daemon** has stopped, but when I check the **service --status-all** it still shows the [ - ] , and I guess gpsd is not working as server yet.

Comment: @M.Becerra : when I use **start-stop-daemon -T --name gpsd** to see status, I see nothing.

Comment: First of all, make sure gpsd is running as a daemon `ps -C "$(xlsclients | cut -d' ' -f3 | paste - -s -d ',')" --ppid 2 --pid 2 --deselect -o tty,args | grep ^?
 | grep gpsd` if it is, kill it with `sudo killall gpsd` and `sudo rm /var/run/gpsd.sock` , according to the documentation provided by yourself.

Comment: @M.Becerra : just used **ps -C "$(xlsclients | cut -d' ' -f3 | paste - -s -d ',')" --ppid 2 --pid 2 --deselect -o tty,args | grep ^? | grep gpsd** and put this command in terminal, then press *enter key* , I see nothing happen,

Comment: That means gpsd is **not** running as a daemon. If you still want to be sure no instance of gpsd is running, do `ps ax | grep gpsd`, again, if theres no ouput, it means it is **not** running.

Comment: @M.Becerra :  **sudo killall gpsd** and **sudo rm /var/run/gpsd.sock** are used: **root@Lab-X230:/home/igor# sudo killall gpsd** give me **gpsd: no process found**, and  **root@Lab-X230:/home/igor# sudo rm /var/run/gpsd.sock** give me **rm: cannot remove '/var/run/gpsd.sock': No such file or directory**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55690/discussion-between-nate-duong-and-m-becerra).